# Swift 3 UIActivity Subclass problems with override

Tags: swift, xcode, overriding, uiactivity

I just upgraded from swift 2 to swift 3 and I am running into some problems with overriding a property.

In swift 2 you could set the activity type like this

```
override func activityType() -> String? {
   return "com.a.string"
}
```

However in swift 3 (in Xcode 8 beta 6) they introduced NS_STRING_ENUM and now we override activityType like this

```
override var activityType() -> UIActivityType? {
    return UIActivityType.customActivityType
}
```

The problem is that Xcode will complain with this:
    Property cannot be an @objc override because its type cannot be represented in Objective-C

One solution i found is to add the annotation @nonobjc to it like so:

```
@nonobjc override var activityType() -> UIActivityType? {
    return UIActivityType.customActivityType
}
```

While this helps make the error go away, this property never gets called...
This is a problem because when the user completes the activity and completionWithItemsHandler() gets called, the activity type is considered nil.

One work around I found is to use an objective-c extension.  It works; it gives me type "horse" like I wanted.

```
@interface Custom_UIActivity (custom)
- (UIActivityType)activityType;
@end

@implementation Custom_UIActivity (custom)
- (UIActivityType)activityType {
    return @"horses";
}
```

My question is how to do it in a pure swift.

Comment: It seems to be a bug of Swift 3 (beta 6) and you can find some thread in [the Apple's dev forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/170059#169260). Using Objective-C code seems to be the only workaround as for now.

Answer (score 8):

In pure Swift3 I am able to compile it using

```
override var activityType: UIActivityType {
    return UIActivityType(rawValue: self.customActivityType.rawValue)
}
```

Comment: The issue was in Xcode 8 beta 6.  Xcode 8 GM resolves the issue.

Comment: ahoo ok nice(y)

Comment: In fact, I tried the same way with already Swift 3.0.1 and everything compiles but the activity is not shown. The same code in objc is working...

Comment: @Susim how to override activityTitle, image and category?